# Transfer files from Windows Server to AWS S3 using SMB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, smb

I need to transfer files from a EC2 Windows server to a AWS S3 bucket using SMB3 in a regular basis. I have tried AWS Data Sync and File Gateway but they require more EC2 memory for the setup. Are there any AWS services that can achieve this? Or what other solution can you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that you can transfer from Windows Server to AWS S3 using AWS DataSync by deploying an agent in EC2 with an instance type of t2.medium. The requirement based on documentation is at least a 2xlarge instance but anything with at least 4GiB memory works but will surely affect the performance. For the setup, I found this blog from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/transferring-data-between-aws-accounts-using-aws-datasync/.